# Unable to update Xcode

Tags: imac, xcode, apple-id, software-update

I am unable to update Xcode: after entering my user id and password I am getting "Your Apple ID has been disabled" error.

Comment: Have you followed [this guide?](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204106)

Comment: I followed,but that does not help. I already reset my password 5 times.

Comment: Contact Apple Support then

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [Apple ID page](http://appleid.apple.com), then `Reset your password`.

If that doesn't work, you'll have to contact [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/contact) for assistance.